# Intersection of two sorted Linked lists in python3?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

My code is unable two print out the new list which is the intersection of two sorted linked list.Its not able to access list inside the function. Please point out the mistake in my code. there is no indentation problem in my code and the algorithm also seems to be fine.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Linked(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self,n):
        new_node = Node(n)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def print_list(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next

    def intersect(self,l1,l2):
        l1 = l1.head
        l2 = l2.head
        dummy = cur = Node(0)
        while l1 and l2:
            if l2.data>l1.data:
                l1=l1.next
            elif l1.data>l2.data:
                l2=l2.next
            else:
                cur.next = l1 or l2
                l1 = l1.next
                l2 = l2.next
            cur = cur.next
        return dummy.next
llist = Linked()
llist1 = Linked()
llist.push(6)
llist.push(4)
llist.push(3)
llist.push(2)
llist.push(1)
llist1.push(8)
llist1.push(6)
llist1.push(4)
llist1.push(2)
l = Linked()
print(l.intersect(llist,llist1).data)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/omsai/Desktop/intersection.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(l.intersect(llist,llist1).data)
  File "C:/Users/omsai/Desktop/intersection.py", line 26, in intersect
    if l2.data>l1.data:
AttributeError: 'Linked' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `Linked.intersect` with two instances of `Linked`, which doesn't have a `data` member.  You need to get the actual nodes out in the `intersect` method:

```
def intersect(self,l1,l2):
    l1 = l1.head
    l2 = l2.head
    dummy = cur = Node(0)
    # ...
```

You probably don't need to call `intersect` with two arguments; it would be enough to intersect one list against another:

```
def intersect(self, olinked):
    thisone = self.head
    otherone = olinked.head
    retval = Linked()
    while thisone and otherone:
        if otherone.data > thisone.data:
            thisone = thisone.next
        elif thisone.data > otherone.data:
            otherone = otherone.next
        else:  # thisone.data == otherone.data
            retval.push(otherone.data)
            thisone = thisone.next
            otherone = otherone.next
    return retval

# ...

llist.intersect(llist1).print_list()
```

Comment: well its now showing the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/omsai/Desktop/intersection.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(l.intersect(llist,llist1).data)
  File "C:/Users/omsai/Desktop/intersection.py", line 33, in intersect
    cur.next = l1.data
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: thanks for the help . it worked. seems like solving questions on leetcode and your own editor is quite different